# Plotting a 3D surface by plotting a function $f(\theta,x,y)$

Tags: plotting

As the title suggests, I was wondering if there is a way to generate a 3D surface by plotting a function $f(x,y,\theta)$ for specific values of $\theta$ using a list and then plotting the whole function by rotating the individual graphs over $\theta = 0 $ to $2\pi$. Any hints or suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Try a `Manipulate`-`ParametricPlot`-combo, where $x$ and $y$ are used in the `ParametricPlot` and the $\theta$ is controlled by `Manpulate`.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[θ_, x_, y_] := Sin[x + y^2] Cos[θ];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[θ, x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
 {{θ, Pi}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/50., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]